# Xcode 9 Alternate App Icons - Invalid Image Path

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode9

I use alternate app icons in my app (which is currently in the App Store). Since upgrading to Xcode 9, I get errors when submitting to the App Store (see screenshots). The alternate icon works properly when running on the simulator/device.

The main app icon is included in the Asset catalog, and the alternate icon is added directly to the project (which I needed to do to get it to work in Xcode 8.3). I've double checked that all the alternate app icon files are part of the app target.

I'm also getting some errors regarding missing required app icon files, which seems suspicious since they're all there as far as I can tell.

I'm using Xcode Server to create my builds, and submitting to the App Store from the integration results page.

Please let me know if you need any other information to help me solve this issue.

**EDIT:** I created an archive manually using Xcode, and that archive was accepted. Looks like this is an issue with archives created by Xcode Server.

[image: App Store upload warning #1]
[image: App Store upload warning #2]
[image: Asset Catalog App Icon]
[image: Info.plist]
[image: Alternate App Icons]